# Star Wars: R2D2 connected to mainframe

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In the original (1977) *Star Wars* film, there was a very brief shot showing a connector being attached to R2D2 so that Rebel mainframes could retrieve and analyse his memories.

Is there a still of that available anywhere?

I'm trying to explain to a journalist friend the concept of hooking a logic analyser to a target system....

Having said that, I must say that I find the whole idea of voluntarily opening ones mind to even friendly interrogation by intellectual superiors incredibly spooky.

Comment: if the question had been "what kind of real-world connector was used as the prop for this scene" that would be an interesting and on-topic question. The question as stated is on-topic but could have been easily self-answered via Disney+, or Amazon, or as the answers point out (one explicitly and the other in how long it took to answer), a fairly cursory search. again, no offense meant so I'll retract the close vote :)

Comment: Well, I don't deal with Amazon and it always takes me a great deal of mental effort to associate Star Wars with Disney: the cantina fight etc. was hardly their style, at least in the 1970s :-) As I've said in a different comment the connector is much less chunky than I thought I remembered... I must admit that it looks half-familiar and it could very easily have been something that the model operators used for remote control.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that is the moment you are looking for:

[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLmOteqmDYc&t=100s)
[image]

Comment: This makes me wonder why they hooked up a cable to him when R2-D2 could have easily ejected the disk that put inside him by Princess Leia. They could have put that disk directly into the mainframe and retrieved the data from that.

Comment: @user57467 that looks firm and solid. - What about wireless data transfer? - That is not our way!

Comment: Thanks, that's the shot although the connector isn't the massive thing with a swing-over latch I thought I remembered... that probably reflects more on my history with 60/70s era mainframes than anything else.

Comment: @user57467 That in part is my point: with a physical attachment to a target system you can access a lot of state that wouldn't normally be available over a public API: storage blocks inaccessible due to wear-levelling and so on. For example, if the disc containing the Death Star's plans had been a malware vector (influencing R2D2 to trust Skywalker and Solo, both unknown to the Rebels), it would be impossible to tell just by asking for a copy of the data, but laying out a complete image of his state (instantaneous and journaled) in a larger system might make intrusion detectable- and curable.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi two ways of looking at star wars - is it a product of its time before we knew wireless data transfer was a thing or is is a security method... wireless data transfers can be tapped in to and recorded, a hardwire connection could have intrusion detection and shielding to ensure data security

Comment: @user57467 End-user systems frequently have ejectable media hardware that servers don't support.

Comment: @user57467 Perhaps it relates to the over-all situation... a rebel alliance having a hodge-podge of resources to work with, and R2D2 happening to be something of a "Swiss Army Knife" robot that seemingly supports interfaces to just about anything. So where Leia had the plans on a cartridge, the rebel base only has equipment that requires a cable connection.

Comment: @AnthonyX I'm now imagining some rebel IT guys connecting a series of dongles and converters to connect a now decades-old maintenance droid to whatever computer system they have.

Comment: @AnthonyX, that's a good point you make.

Answer (score 15):

I found this (full width, reasonably high resolution) picture fairly quickly via Google.

[image: R2-D2 Hookup]

(I could probably take a better screen snapshot from my DVD copy, but my regular computer at home does not have a DVD player.  *O tempora, o mores!*)

Comment: Good catch. I thought the OP was talking about the extendable arm, which if I recall correctly, little Artoo plugged into a power socket... now why wouldn't a space fairing universe have created typed plugs....

Comment: @CGCampbell: My understanding is that wasn't a power socket, but rather the Death Star computer security system could respond to intrusion with high voltage.

Comment: @CGCampbell no, definitely not which is why I carefully wrote "connector being attached to R2D2". However what I thought I remembered was more like this sort of thing https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/hires/0587231010_hires.jpg with a single pullin/latch lever although after this many years its hardly surprising that my recollection is flawed.